# this regex is not working in codeigniter's uri

Tags: php, mysql, regex, codeigniter, url

Here is the route with regex:

```
$route["searchresults/((parameter|type|something)-([0-9]+)\/)+"] = 'somecontroller';
```

here is an example:

```
www.somedomain.com/searchresults/parameter-21/
```

The above url is not being recongized by codeigniter's routes, and is saying 404.  What is wrong with the regex in the route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be due to a the trailing slash in your regex, you may have more luck by either removing it or making it optional:

```
$route["searchresults/((parameter|type|something)-([0-9]+)\/*)+"] = 'somecontroller';
```